# Revert Visual Studio 2019 Update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I upgraded from VS 2019 16.0.3 to 16.0.4 and it broke debugging for some of my projects.

VS 2017 has [a page for downloading old versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017), but I can't find something similar for VS 2019.

How can I downgrade my version of VS 2019?

Comment: do you have a system restore point so that you can revert?

Comment: @magicandre1981 As in revert my whole computer?

Comment: yes. I create a snapshot in the VM all time before I update VS2017/2019 to be able to rollback in case I have issues.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That is a good idea. Sadly, I do not have a restore point

Comment: [submit the issue to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and hope they fix it soon. alos try delete obj/bin and maybe .vs folder and hope debugging works now.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Classic -_-, clearing bin and obj did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Vote on a suggestion for this here: [Introduce the ability to roll back a Visual Studio Update](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/395028/introduce-the-ability-to-roll-back-a-visual-studio.html)

Comment: This is the place for the Mac installers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175361/revert-visual-studio-2019-update

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now there is [a page for downloading old versions of VS 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history) as well.

Comment: That page includes Professional and Enterprise, but not Community

Comment: @farlee2121 Unfortunately. Same as for VS 2017.

Comment: Hmm. That's true. That's worth an accepted answer

Comment: AAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarght

Comment: It works if you download the Enterprise installer for the version you want, but use it to install Community instead.

Comment: @Ghar You can use it to install Community 2017, but not Community 2019.

Comment: @RadoslavVoydanovich I just installed previous version of Community 2019 (v16.9.6, the newest version is v16.10.0) with that link

Comment: @MariuszPawelski How? For me, that installer only provides Community version of 2017 edition.

Comment: @MariuszPawelski Oh, it shows for me as "available update" under "Installed", because I haven't uninstalled it in the first place. Good to know, thank you!

Comment: @MariuszPawelski Still the question: how? I can only install VS Enterprise with those installers, it's installed next to the VS Community (apparently it's a combined installer) and offers an upgrade for VS Enterprise but no way to install, say, VS Community 16.10

Comment: @JvO I think you need to uninstall you Community version first, then download installer for enterpise and run it, then close first window where you choose what to install (titled like "Installing - Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 - 16.0.7"), then go to "Available" tab and there should be your community version.
It's not appearing now when I test it but it was back when I wrote the comment. That's why I assume you must uninstall it first (but this is just a guess...). If it doesn't work then maybe Microsoft changed something.

Comment: Yeah, you need to completely uninstall Visual Studio, including its installer. What a bummer...

Answer (score 1):

as I said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295288/could-not-run-the-generateresource-task-because-msbuild-could-not-create-or-co)

I had the same Error (in version 16.9.3)
but By Repairing Visual Studio 2019, Updating last version of windows 10,
close VS, delete .vs hidden folder (under solution folder) ,bin and obj folder then restart your VS .
Fortunately My problem was solved.