# Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x64"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-4.5

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise version 15.7.1 and .NET Framework 4.5.

I just installed Windows 10 Update version 10.0.18363 build 18363.

I can build other projects in the same Solution, but for this one project, I am getting this error while building

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3045,5): 
error MSB4216: 
Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x64".  
Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run.

Error   MSB4028 The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "FilesWritten" parameter. 
Object does not match target type.  my-project-name C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   3066
```

How can I fix this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try these:

**1)** add these xml node in your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup> 

<GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>CurrentArchitecture</GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
<GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>CurrentRuntime</GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
    
</PropertyGroup>
```

**2)** add a system environment variable called `DisableOutOfProcTaskHost` and set its value to `true`.

**Or** set `DISABLEOUTOFPROCTASKHOST` to `1`.

**3)** since your **VS2017** is too old, I suggest you could update your **VS2017** to the latest version in case there are some fixes. Or [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2017).

**Also**, make sure that you have installed the workload **.Net Core cross-platform development** in vs installer.

[image]

**4)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder then restart your VS to test again. **Besides**, you can change your target framework version to `net framework 4.6.1` and **Configuration** to `Any CPU`.

Comment: Yay ! I did all 4 steps, and now I can compile this project successfully. I now have VS 2017 Version 15.9.27. Thank you soooo much for your help !!!

Comment: Had issue running `dotnet build` against an older 4.8 winforms application and performing step 1) allowed the dotnet cli to build the app.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Error (in version 16.9.3) but By Repairing Visual Studio 2019, Updating last version of windows 10, close VS, delete .vs hidden folder (under solution folder) ,bin and obj folder then restart your VS . Fortunately My problem was solved.