# Could not run the "LC" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x64"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I am using VS 2019. Once the project is cloned from bitbucket, I am able to build the solution. If I try to build after cleaning the solution or rebuild, I am getting this error.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not run the "LC" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x64".
Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run.

I have updated VS but it did not help.

1. Updated VS 2019
2. deleted .vs folder obj folder and debug folder
3. restarted the machine

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience,

1. You can try to add the following code in the csproj file: (unload the project, then double-click the project to enter)

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>CurrentArchitecture</GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
   <GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>CurrentRuntime</GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2. Add an environment variable `DisableOutOfProcTaskHost` and set its value to `true`. Or set it to 1.

Update:

It was due to crowdstrike running in the machine.

Comment: I tried with these steps, but no luck

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed that affect msbuild, try disabling them. You can also try to reinstall vs2019 using installer, but I suggest you use the latest version of 2022. This link may help you. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/msbuild-amd-x64-not-working/1387989?viewtype=solutions

Comment: i have installed VS 2022 yesterday, still same issue. Need to check on extensions

Comment: Maybe you need to try removing msbuild, and reinstall https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2022#install-msbuild. Do you have the same problem in your new program?

Comment: I found an issue similar to yours, you can try to see if it solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64313043/16764901

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Issue is resolved now. It was due to crowdstrike running in the machine.

Comment: I have edited the answer,you could mark it as the answer. Thanks. That would help the person has the same issue.